# The required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(); the supplied value "xyz" is an atomic value

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the below XML and I am trying to compare the values in  under each  to a variable with multiple values separated by '|'. I want to output the values from the variable that did not match with the ones in  for each group. Below is the XML and XSLT-

```
<RegionLOBs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:statutorytype="us-stat-2020-annual-stmt-pc"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance"
    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xe.com/iso4217.htm"
    xmlns:stat="urn:www-iasa-org/tempuri">
    <Group>
        <Region>AL</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>AR</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>AZ</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>CA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>CO</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>CT</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>DC</Region>
        <LOB>WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Surety</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>DE</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>GA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>IA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ExcessWorkersCompensation ProductsLiability PrivatePassengerAutoNoFault OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>ID</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>IL</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>IN</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ExcessWorkersCompensation ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>KS</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability PrivatePassengerAutoNoFault OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>KY</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability PrivatePassengerAutoNoFault OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>LA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>MA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>MD</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>ME</Region>
        <LOB>Fire OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Surety BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>MI</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>MN</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability PrivatePassengerAutoNoFault OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>MO</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>MS</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>MT</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>NC</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>ND</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability PrivatePassengerAutoNoFault OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>NE</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>NH</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>NJ</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>NM</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>NV</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>NY</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>OH</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ExcessWorkersCompensation ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>OK</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>OR</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>PA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ExcessWorkersCompensation ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>RI</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>SC</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>SD</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>TN</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>TX</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>UT</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>VA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>WA</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>WI</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>WV</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>WY</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivateFlood PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery HomeownersMultiplePeril InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>AK</Region>
        <LOB>Fire WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence ProductsLiability Surety InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>FL</Region>
        <LOB>Fire Earthquake WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence OtherLiabilityClaimsMade ProductsLiability CommercialAutoNoFault OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Fidelity Surety BurglaryAndTheft BoilerAndMachinery InlandMarine</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>VT</Region>
        <LOB>Fire WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence ProductsLiability OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability OtherCommercialAutoLiability AlliedLines PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage Surety BoilerAndMachinery</LOB>
    </Group>
    <Group>
        <Region>HI</Region>
        <LOB>WorkersCompensation OtherLiabilityOccurrence Surety</LOB>
    </Group>
</RegionLOBs>
```

The version I am using is XSLT 2.0 and looks as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Page_14_EMC"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:statutorytype="us-stat-2020-annual-stmt-pc"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xe.com/iso4217.htm"
    xmlns:stat="urn:www-iasa-org/tempuri" exclude-result-prefixes="xs wd" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="single_quote">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ampersand">
        <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:variable name="LOB_Hier">
        <xsl:text>Fire|AlliedLines|MultiplePerilCrop|FederalFlood|PrivateCrop|PrivateFlood|FarmownersMultiplePeril|HomeownersMultiplePeril|CommercialMultiplePerilNonLiabilityPortion|CommercialMultiplePerilLiabilityPortion|MortgageGuaranty|OceanMarine|InlandMarine|FinancialGuaranty|MedicalProfessionalLiability|Earthquake|GroupAccidentAndHealth|CreditAccidentAndHealth|CollectivelyRenewableAccidentAndHealth|NonCancelableAccidentAndHealth|GuaranteedRenewableAccidentAndHealth|NonRenewableForStatedReasonsOnly|OtherAccidentOnly|MedicareTitleXviiiExemptFromStateTaxesOrFees|AllOtherAccidentAndHealth|FederalEmployeesHealthBenefitsPlanPremium|WorkersCompensation|OtherLiabilityOccurrence|OtherLiabilityClaimsMade|ExcessWorkersCompensation|ProductsLiability|PrivatePassengerAutoNoFault|OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability|CommercialAutoNoFault|OtherCommercialAutoLiability|PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage|CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage|Aircraft|Fidelity|Surety|BurglaryAndTheft|BoilerAndMachinery|Credit|International|Warranty</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($LOB_Hier, '\|')">
            <xsl:call-template name="repeatable">
                <xsl:with-param name="LOB_Hier" select="tokenize($LOB_Hier,'\|')" />
            </xsl:call-template> 
           
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="repeatable" match="RegionLOBs">
        <xsl:param name="LOB_Hier"/>
        <LOBNotFound>
            <xsl:for-each select="Group">
                <Region>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Region"/>
                </Region>
                <xsl:variable name="GroupLOB" select="LOB"/>
                <MissingLOBs>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($GroupLOB,$LOB_Hier)">
                            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$LOB_Hier"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </MissingLOBs>
                
            </xsl:for-each>
        </LOBNotFound>      
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error I am getting when I am running this transformation is 'The required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(); the supplied value "Fire" is an atomic value'

How do I make it work? Appreciate any suggestions for resolution.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of your `xsl:for-each` is an atomic value, not a node from the XML structure. So, when you call the "repeatable" template by name, and then inside of it attempt to use an XPath, it is complaining that you can't use an XPath axis on a string.

You could create a variable selecting the `RegionLOBs` element and then instead of calling by name, apply-templates selecting that variable as the context.

Additionally, there is an issue with: `<xsl:when test="contains($GroupLOB,$LOB_Hier)">`

`$LOB_Hier` has a sequence of values, so it complains that you cannot use a sequence for `contains()`. You could instead tokenize the `GoupLOB` by space and test the sets of values to see if there is an intersection: `<xsl:when test="tokenize($GroupLOB, ' ') = $LOB_Hier">`

Applied to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_Page_14_EMC"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:statutorytype="us-stat-2020-annual-stmt-pc"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xe.com/iso4217.htm"
    xmlns:stat="urn:www-iasa-org/tempuri" exclude-result-prefixes="xs wd" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="single_quote">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ampersand">
        <xsl:text>&amp;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:variable name="LOB_Hier">
        <xsl:text>Fire|AlliedLines|MultiplePerilCrop|FederalFlood|PrivateCrop|PrivateFlood|FarmownersMultiplePeril|HomeownersMultiplePeril|CommercialMultiplePerilNonLiabilityPortion|CommercialMultiplePerilLiabilityPortion|MortgageGuaranty|OceanMarine|InlandMarine|FinancialGuaranty|MedicalProfessionalLiability|Earthquake|GroupAccidentAndHealth|CreditAccidentAndHealth|CollectivelyRenewableAccidentAndHealth|NonCancelableAccidentAndHealth|GuaranteedRenewableAccidentAndHealth|NonRenewableForStatedReasonsOnly|OtherAccidentOnly|MedicareTitleXviiiExemptFromStateTaxesOrFees|AllOtherAccidentAndHealth|FederalEmployeesHealthBenefitsPlanPremium|WorkersCompensation|OtherLiabilityOccurrence|OtherLiabilityClaimsMade|ExcessWorkersCompensation|ProductsLiability|PrivatePassengerAutoNoFault|OtherPrivatePassengerAutoLiability|CommercialAutoNoFault|OtherCommercialAutoLiability|PrivatePassengerAutoPhysicalDamage|CommercialAutoPhysicalDamage|Aircraft|Fidelity|Surety|BurglaryAndTheft|BoilerAndMachinery|Credit|International|Warranty</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="context" select="RegionLOBs"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($LOB_Hier, '\|')">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$context">
                <xsl:with-param name="LOB_Hier" select="tokenize($LOB_Hier,'\|')" />
            </xsl:apply-templates> 
            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="repeatable" match="RegionLOBs">
        <xsl:param name="LOB_Hier"/>
        <LOBNotFound>
            <xsl:for-each select="Group">
                <Region>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Region"/>
                </Region>
                <xsl:variable name="GroupLOB" select="LOB"/>
                 <MissingLOBs>
                   <xsl:sequence select="$LOB_Hier[not(. = tokenize($GroupLOB, ' '))]"/>
                 </MissingLOBs>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </LOBNotFound>      
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen. I tried using this but the output does not give me any a difference of LOBs (no value in MissingLOBs) for each region.

Comment: what do you want it to test for or produce? It looked like you were testing whether any of the `$LOB_Hier` values were contained in the `$GroupLOB`, and your LOB have values that are in that LOB_Hier list.

Comment: I want to list out the values in $LOB_Hier that do not match with the what is in $GroupLOB for each Region. Example - for region AL, we do not have values like MultiplePerilCrop,FederalFlood,PrivateCrop,PrivateFlood etc in the GroupLOB. So I want to output all these values from LOB_Hier list.

Comment: okay, I see. I've updated the answer to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you Mads. It works!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `xsl:call-template` inside of `xsl:for-each select="tokenize($LOB_Hier, '\|')"`, that is, inside of a `for-each` over a sequence of strings (strings are atomic values) so in your called template the context item is a simple string. Yet you pretend you want to process child elements named `Group` with e.g. `xsl:for-each select="Group"` inside of the called template, presumably child elements of some input node.

So before the `xsl:for-each select="tokenize($LOB_Hier, '\|')"`, you need to store a node, e.g. the context node with `<xsl:variable name="root-node" select="."/>` and pass that on also as a parameter to the template you call to then use `$root-node/Group` where you want to process the `Group` children or probably rather `$root-node/RegionLOBs/Group` if I read your document structure correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen. It now gives me issue saying 'A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second argument of fn:contains() ("Fire", "AlliedLines")'

Comment: @VJain, I think Mads has already covered that in his response as well and made a suggestion on how to avoid it, so look there.

Comment: Or state what kind of value you expect `<xsl:param name="LOB_Hier"/>` to have in the called template, are you wanting to pass in the full sequence of string values, as you do with `<xsl:with-param name="LOB_Hier" select="tokenize($LOB_Hier,'\|')" />` or did you perhaps just want to pass in a single value, like the context item of the `for-each` with e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="LOB_Hier" select="."/>`?